# FreeMarker: Check if map value is null

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

I have a Map whose key and value and custom classes. The key class is called `Position` and is instantiated with two int (for example `new Position(2, 4)`.

I got rid of this Position class and converted the map to a `SimpleHash` in order to use it with Freemarker. I now have a `SimpleHash` whose key is a String remapping Position values (for example `"2 4"`) and whose value is either `null` or a `Lot` (custom) class.

In the template I need to check if the value of a given item in the SimpleMap (passed as `map`) is either null or a Lot instance.

```
        <#list mapMinY..mapMaxY as y>
            <tr>
                <#list mapMinX..mapMaxX as x>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <!-- Check if map[x + " " + y] is null -->
                            ${x}, ${y}
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </#list>
            </tr>
        </#list>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since freemarker is kind of odd when it comes to null values have two ways to solve it.
 1.Treat it as a missing value :

```
${map[x + " " + y]!}
   do Stuff
${map[x + " " + y]!}
```

2.Just convert that check into a true/false check.
This could be done by using a utility class whith a isNull(Object obj) function.

```
utilClass.isNull(map[x + " " + y])==true
```

Comment: There's no need for custom utilities here. FreeMarker has quite a few dedicated operators for dealing with null/missing values (see my answer below). (The `== true` check also looks rather strange...) `utilClass.isNull` couldn't tell a null from a missing key either, as it basically just gets what `Map.get` returns, which is `null` in both cases.

Answer (score 9):

Use the `??` operator.

```
<#if map[x + " " + y]??>It's not null<#else>It's null or missing</#if>
```

See also [the related part of the Manual](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_missing).